# What is 1 << 0?

Tags: c++, syntax, bit-manipulation

```
 enum
    {
      kFlag_FPS         = 1 << 0,
      kFlag_Help        = 1 << 1,
      kFlag_RedBlue3D   = 1 << 2,
    }
```

I am trying to understand what this code is I don't quite know what:

```
1 << 0
```

means?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: It's just to make it look consistent.

Comment: It is bitwise shifting to the left but I don't know how to explain that.

Comment: 1 << 0 is 1 shifted left 0 times, or 1 * 2^0. So, it's 1.

Comment: @Mysticial "Consistent" means format, the code looks good. The idea is just to assign a number into variables. Here they use bits number system to assign a simple variable :D by shifting 1 to the left in binary. i,e var =1; same as var = 0000 0001 and var=2 is var=0000 0010. C language is crazy :D

Answer (score 87, accepted):

From [MSDN - Shift Operators: >> and <<](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/336xbhcz.aspx)

> The left-shift operator causes the bit pattern in the first operand to
>   be shifted to the left by the number of bits specified by the second
>   operand. Bits vacated by the shift operation are zero-filled. This is
>   a logical shift instead of a shift-and-rotate operation.

This means that the user is taking the bits value of `1` and shifting the bits to the left based on the right number.

That means that in this case, their values will look like this in binary.

```
1 << 0 = `0000 0001`
1 << 1 = `0000 0010`
1 << 2 = `0000 0100`
```

The first shift is not necessary, but it looks more consistent with the rest.

Comment: You should avoid referencing 'MSDN' as a reliable source for c++ language reference IMHO

Comment: @g-makulik: I tend to agree, but this particular MSDN documentation appears to be accurate.

Comment: Even if a bit late, I would add that those operations result in the different values being powers of 2. I mention this because sometimes this construct is used precisely because of that property.

Answer (score 22):

`1 << 0` is 1 shifted to the left by 0 positions, which is just 1.

Answer (score 11):

`x << y` - means shift bits of x to the left (to larger value) y times.
In math, this looks like:
`x * (2^y)` or `x * pow(2, y)`

Answer (score 5):

It could have been simply

```
enum
    {
      kFlag_FPS         = 1,
      kFlag_Help        = 1 << 1,
      kFlag_RedBlue3D   = 1 << 2,
    }
```

but the coder likes more symmetry.

Answer (score 5):

The `<<` operator is a bit shifter.  So `1 << 2`, is equal to `4` as you take `1` and shift by `2` bits.  When using `1 << 0`, that has no impact on the value and is probably there to make everything appear consistent

Answer (score 1):

`>> (Signed right shift)` if the number is negative, then 1 is used as a filler and if the number is positive, then 0 is used as a filler.

```
       int x = -4; 
       System.out.println(x>>1);  //output -2  
       int y = 4; 
       System.out.println(y>>1); //output 2
```

`>>> (Unsigned right shift)` In Java, the operator ‘>>>’ is unsigned right shift operator. It always fills 0 irrespective of the sign of the number.
       // x is stored using 32 bit 2's complement form.
       // Binary representation of -1 is all 1s (111..1)

```
       int x = -1;   
       System.out.println(x>>>29);  // The value of 'x>>>29' is 00...0111 
       System.out.println(x>>>30);  // The value of 'x>>>30' is 00...0011  
       System.out.println(x>>>31);  // The value of 'x>>>31' is 00...0001
```

Answer (score 1):

It's 1.

**Why is it used?**

To follow a bit shifting pattern.

1 as int 32 is:

```
00000000 000000000 00000000 00000001
```

1 << 1 shifts left once, yielding 2

```
00000000 000000000 00000000 00000010
```

So, 1 << 0 shifts left zero times, yielding 1

```
00000000 000000000 00000000 00000001
```

A common pattern is to use this in an enum:

```
enum {
   firstOption = 0,
   secondOption = (1 << 0),
   thirdOption = (1 << 1),
   // etc.
}
```

To maintain the pattern, do:

```
enum {
   firstOption = (0 << 0), // 0 shifted 0 times to the left == 0
   secondOption = (1 << 0), // 1 shifted 0 times to the left == 1
   thirdOption = (1 << 1), // 1 shifted 1 time to the left == 2
   // etc.
}
```

For clarity, I prefer:

```
enum {
   firstOption = 0,
   secondOption = 1,
   thirdOption = (1 << 1), // 2
   // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for the answer to this question myself, but I was more curious about the why. Here is a [link](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/) that properly explains the why. Why not just use standard enums that takes integers as their values?
Apparently, using bitwise operators for enums are great for defining flags.

```
// Powers of two
[Flags] public enum AttackType {
    // Decimal     // Binary
    None   = 0,    // 000000
    Melee  = 1,    // 000001
    Fire   = 2,    // 000010
    Ice    = 4,    // 000100
    Poison = 8     // 001000
}
// Label          Binary   Decimal
// Melee:         000001 = 1
// Fire:          000010 = 2
// Melee | Fire:  000011 = 3
```

With the above you can combine multiple flags/enums and have a unique value without having to define it in the actual enum class. Use this [link](https://www.alanzucconi.com/2015/07/26/enum-flags-and-bitwise-operators/) to find out more.